# Unable to uncheck radio button in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-radiobutton

I am new in Android programming so right below the following question:

I am unable to uncheck a radio button of an element from a ListView in Android. If a property in the DB is true, the radio button should be checked, if it is false, it should be unchecked, but the currently checked button is not being recognised in the onClick() method, therefore it is not being unchecked.

[This is the following code from my CustomListAdapter:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePUMm.png)

or:

```
        mSelectedRB = holder.activeVCardRadioButton;
        if (contact.getStatus().equals(Status.ACTIVE.toString())) {
            mSelectedRB.setChecked(true);
            currentVCardId = contact.getId();
        }
        if(holder.activeVCardRadioButton != null) {
            holder.activeVCardRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (position != mSelectedPosition && (mSelectedRB != null)) { 
                        mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                        mSelectedRB.setActivated(false);
                       kontaktenDataSource.inactivateVCard(currentVCardId);

                    }

                    mSelectedPosition = position;
                    mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
                         kontaktenDataSource.activateVCard(contact.getId());
                    currentVCardId = contact.getId();
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(true);
                }
            });

        }
```

This is the xml in which I placed the radiobutton:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

In the first IF of the onClick() method,                             mSelectedRB.setChecked(false); is not working properly and I don't understand why!
If someone could come with some suggestions, I'd be glad!

Thanks,
Maria.

Comment: If you have just one `RadioButton` per list item then it does not make much sense to have it, instead consider using a `CheckBox`. Check this tutorial out for `CheckBox` -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_checkbox_control.htm

Comment: Can you post your full CustomListAdapter code, also post your layouts for the list view and list view item?

Comment: @ParagKadam I have a list, and in this list only one element can be checked at once, that's why I need a radio button :)

Comment: @YawAsare, I have added the xml code, the CustomListAdapater code is huge.